# How to maximize performance?

Tags: c#, database, performance, linq, dynamic-linq

I have a problem which I cannot seem to get around no matter how hard I try.

This company works in market analysis, and have pretty large tables (300K - 1M rows) and MANY columns (think 250-300) which we do some calculations on.

I´ll try to get straight to the problem:

The problem is the filtering of the data. All databases I´ve tried so far are way too slow to select data and return it.

At the moment I am storing the entire table in memory and filtering using dynamic LINQ.

However, while this is quite fast (about 100 ms to filter 250 000 rows) I need better results than this...

Is there any way I can change something in my code (not the data model) which could speed the filtering up?

I have tried using:

> DataTable.Select which is slow. Dynamic LINQ which is better, but
>   still too slow. Normal LINQ (just for testing purposes) which almost
>   is good enough. Fetching from MySQL and do the processing later on
>   which is badass slow.

At the beginning of this project we thought that some high-performance database would be able to handle this, but I tried:

H2 (IKVM)
HSQLDB (compiled ODBC-driver)
CubeSQL
MySQL
SQL
SQLite
...

And they are all very slow to interface .NET and get results from.

I have also tried splitting the data into chunks and combining them later in runtime to make the total amount of data which needs filtering smaller.

Is there any way in this universe I can make this faster?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I just want to add that I have not created this database in question.

To add some figures, if I do a simple select of 2 field in the database query window (SQLyog) like this (visit_munic_name is indexed):

```
SELECT key1, key2 FROM table1 WHERE filter1 = filterValue1
```

It takes 125 milliseconds on 225639 rows.

Why is it so slow? I have tested 2 different boxes.

Of course they must change someting, obviously?

Comment: That's not really a large number of rows, to be honest. Sounds to me like the database structure needs some serious attention.

Comment: Have you checked what is slow when usign DB - network request itself or SQL query execution on DB side? If network request/response is slow - see whether you can host DB close to application, otherwise tune sql query eprformance, table indexes, so on

Comment: You say that selecting data is slow with all the databases you've used. This raises a couple of red flags in my mind. Are you doing any complicated joins in your selects? Do you have complicated where clauses? Is your database correctly indexed?

Comment: does not sound as a very big database to me, if it needs to be faster i'd see if you can plug an SSD into your box, that should defenitley speed things up. The number of columns might make it a good candidate for column oriented databses. That stores data on disk differently that might speed up your DB.

Comment: 1M rows is a small dataset for most databases.

Comment: AndrewBarber, exactly! That´s why I wonder why queries are slow. And yes we see performance increasing with indexing of course. 

sll, we have tried to measure more exact what is slow, we´ll continue doing this.

@CadentOrange, no joins, just one table with one (1) filter, like: select key1, key2, key3 from table1 where filter1 = filterValue1. Normal stuff.

gjvdkamp, We are currently using a Hyper-V 2x2.4 GHz with 16 GB RAM and loading everything in memory.

PanagiotisKanavos, true.

Comment: What about the index then? Does it cover the filter column? Is the filter column the first in the index or have you created one index with XX columns? Querying an index whose first column is the filter and contains the select values should not even be measurable - UNLESS the filter returns a large number of records, in which case you can't really blame the database. How many records does the query return?  Your queries should be as selective as possible, otherwise there is not much point in using a database

Comment: It looks like the column you're filtering on is not indexed, or if it is it could be that the index is highly fragmented. You can verify this by running the DBCC SHOWCONTIG command. I'd try DBCC SHOWCONTIG('tablename') as a starting point. See http://bit.ly/AsNWRE for more options.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your comment. The filtering might be fast, but I also have to return the data :)

Basically, in the end, some calculations are to be done on the data (like, sum, median etc), and sadly MySQL/H2/HSQLDB is quite slow at this (HSQLDB was the best when I tested). So, I have to do this in memory, which is extremely fast. However, if the data itself takes many ms to return, well, then... it´s hard.

Comment: Relational databases are very good at performing simple aggregates like sum, median, average so you don't really have to return all the data. Analytical databases actually precalculate those aggregates so you don't even have to calculate them. You can use an OLAP product like Mondrian on top of MySQL if you insist on using open source software. Personally I've created far bigger data marts with SQL Server and cubes that allow ad-hoc processing in Excel PivotTables with no perceptible delay. It's not the server itself, it's the use of a star schema and cubes that allows fast queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, well actually, they are not very good at aggregates in the measurements we made. LINQ is much faster in every aspect, only HSQLDB with custom compiled median function is near the performance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, You said above "UNLESS the filter returns a large number of records, in which case you can't really blame the database.". Well, who should I blame then? If I have to return the rows? Even if I execute the queries in for example SQLyog there is a delay in the select. The only databases that were up to the performance we needed was H2 and HSQLDB, but H2 couldn´t handle too many requests at the same time when we tested, so HSQLDB was the winner in this case. H2 was however faster at some other things though.

Answer (score 5):

You do not explain what exactly you want to do, or why filtering a lot of rows is important. Why should it matter how fast you can filter 1M rows to get an aggregate if your database can precalculate that aggregate for you? In any case it seems you are using the wrong tools for the job.

*On one hand*, 1M rows is a small number of rows for most databases. As long as you have the proper indexes, querying shouldn't be a big problem. I suspect that either you do not have indexes on your query columns or you want to perform ad-hoc queries on non-indexed columns.

Furthermore, it doesn't matter which database you use if your data schema is wrong for the job. Analytical applications typically use star schemas to allow much faster queries for a lot more data than you describe.

All databases used for analysis purposes use special data structures which require that you transform your data to a form they like. 
For typical relational databases you have to create star schemas that are combined with cubes to precalculate aggregates. 
Column databases store data in a columnar format usually combined with compression to achieve fast analytical queries, but they require that you learn to query them in their own language, which may be very different than the SQL language most people are accustomed to.

*On the other hand*, the way you query (LINQ or DataTable.Select or whatever) has minimal effect on performance. Picking the proper data structure is much more important.

For instance, using a Dictionary<> is much faster than using any of the techniques you mentioned. A dictionary essentially checks for single values in memory. Executing DataTable.Select without indexes, using LINQ to Datasets or to Objects  is essentially the same as scanning all entries of an array or a List<> for a specific value,because that is what all these methods do - scan an entire list sequentially.

The various LINQ providers do not do the job of a database. They do not optimize your queries. They just execute what you tell them to execute. Even doing a binary search on a sorted list is faster than using the generic LINQ providers.

There are various things you can try, depending on what you need to do:

- If you are looking for a quick way to slice and dice your data, use an existing product like  PowerPivot functionality of Excel 2010. PowerPivot loads and compresses MANY millions of rows in an in-memory columnar format and allows you to query your data just as you would with a Pivot table, and even define joins with other in memory sources.
- If you want a more repeatable process you can either create the appropriate star schemas in a relational database or use a columnar database. In either case you will have to write the scripts to load your data in the proper structures.
- If you are creating your own application you really need to investigate the various algorithms and structures used by other similar tools either for in memory.